# How to get confidence interval for $\sigma$ in linear regression in R?

Tags: regression

When using the `lm()` function in R, the `confint()` function gives the confidence interval for the intercept and the coefficients of the regressors, but no for $\sigma$. How can I get that one?

Answer (score 3):

I used the analytic formula:

```
modelo <- lm(I(log(M))~I(log(Y))+I(log(r)))

sigma <- sigma(modelo)
sigma

n <- length(M)
k <- 2
alpha <- 0.05

lower <- (n-(k+1))*sigma^2/qchisq(alpha/2, df = n-(k+1), lower.tail = FALSE)
upper <- (n-(k+1))*sigma^2/qchisq(1-alpha/2, df = n-(k+1), lower.tail = FALSE)

confint.sigma <- round(sqrt(c(lower, upper)), 4)
names(confint.sigma) <- c("lower", "upper")
confint.sigma
```

This works, but it would be useful if there is a function that computes that automatically and yields far less output.

Comment: Who needs confidence intervals for $\sigma$? I think it would be *not* useful to compute this automatically or add it somehow as a feature. R, the way it is now, is already cluttered enough with specialized features (I wouldn't be surprised however that there isn't some package that computes this confidence interval for sigma based on the input of an lm-object).

Comment: Well, confidence intervals for $\sigma$ might be useful for planification of further experiments ...